# Erlang - Transfer between files - MUTEX

Tags: concurrency, erlang, mutex

I have this code for running a simple bank account.
There are two deposit methods and a test method for initialising parallel deposits to the account.

Would someone help me to implement a function to transfer money between 2 accounts, and add mutex to prevent a deadlock?

```
-module(bank).
-export([account/1, start/0, stop/0, deposit1/1, deposit2/1, get_bal/0, set_bal/1, withdraw/1]).

%test

-export ([test/3,user/3]).

account(Balance) ->
receive
    {set, NewBalance} ->
        account(NewBalance);
    {get, From} ->
        From ! {balance, Balance},
        account(Balance);
    {deposit, Amount, From} ->
        NewBalance = Balance + Amount,
        From ! {deposit, Amount, NewBalance},
        account(NewBalance);
    {withdraw, Amount, From} when Amount > Balance ->
        From ! {error, {insufficient_funds, Amount, Balance}},
        account(Balance);
    {withdraw, Amount, From} ->
        NewBalance = Balance - Amount,
        From ! {withdrawal, Amount, NewBalance},
        account(NewBalance);    
    stop -> ok
end.





start() ->
    Account_PID = spawn(bank, account, [0]),
    register(account_process, Account_PID).

stop() ->
    account_process ! stop,
    unregister(account_process).

set_bal(B) ->
    account_process ! {set, B}.

get_bal() ->
    account_process ! {get, self()},
    receive
        {balance, B} -> B
    end.

deposit1(Amount) ->
    OldBalance = get_bal(),
    NewBalance = OldBalance + Amount,
    set_bal(NewBalance).

deposit2(Amount) when Amount > 0 ->
    account_process ! {deposit, Amount, self()},
    receive
        {deposit, Amount, NewBalance} ->
            {ok, NewBalance}
    end.

withdraw(Amount) when Amount > 0 ->
    account_process ! {withdraw, Amount, self()},
    receive
        {withdrawal, Amount, NewBalance} ->
            {ok, NewBalance};
        Error ->
            Error
    end.


test(Nbuser, Nbdeposit, Method) ->
    start(),
    done = spawn_users(Nbuser,Nbdeposit,Method,self()),
    receive_loop(Nbuser),
    Res = (get_bal() == Nbdeposit*Nbuser),
    stop(),
    Res.

spawn_users(0,_Nbdeposit,_Method,_Pid) -> done;
spawn_users(Nbuser,Nbdeposit,Method,Pid) ->
    spawn(?MODULE,user,[Nbdeposit,Method,Pid]),
    spawn_users(Nbuser-1,Nbdeposit,Method,Pid).

receive_loop(0) -> done;
receive_loop(N) ->
    receive
        end_deposit -> receive_loop(N-1)
    end.

user(0,_,Pid) ->
    get_bal(), % to be sure that with method deposit1, the last set_bal is processed
    Pid ! end_deposit;
user(N,Method,Pid) ->
    ?MODULE:Method(1),
    user(N-1,Method,Pid).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your account process manages one single account, as it is a registered process, you cannot manage with this code more than one account.

You need first to decide if you will extend your account/1 function to manage multiple accounts in a single process, or if you want to create a bank process which will manage multiple "single account processes" identified for example by an account number and/or an owner and the association to their pids.

Then you will have to define the message sequence used for deposit, check, withdraw and transfer use cases. Using synchronous and asynchronous protocol (and I guess some timeout) it will be possible to guarantee the consistency of the data, and avoid any dead lock.

Erlang code is different than C++ or java object oriented code. The "methods" (actually all implemented in the receive block of your account/1 function) are executed in the account process: there is no concurrency to fear there. Same thing for the interface functions such as withdraw/1 which are executed in the client process.

Saying this, you can see that the code for deposit2/1 is safe since it has a clear separation of each role (interface and account balance management), but deposit1/1 is unsafe since the interface is doing the operation on the balance, in the client process, using 2 separate accesses to the server (account) processes to update the balance. If 2 requests are coming at the same time, you may have a balance error:

[image: race condition with the deposit1 method. diagram made with "plantuml"]

It looks like this question is about homework or self study, so I let you find a solution. I hope this can help you. I put here an example using one process per account, although I don't think it is a good architecture; it should manage the dead lock.

[image: account transfer use case]